# inserting data from perl into mysql

Tags: sql, perl, dbi

I'm trying to insert data produced by perl into an oracle database table using perl DBI. Its the first time I've tried this so its likely I'm making a simple mistake.

What i'm using at the moment is:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect ('dbi:Oracle:geosgen','student','train')
  || die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";

  $sql = "INSERT INTO MYTEST VALUES ($series, $sheet, $maxlat, $minlat, $maxlong, $minlong)";

  $create = $dbh->do($sql);
  print "Content-type:text/html\n\n\n";
if($Create){
print "Success";
}
else{
print "Failure<br/>$DBI::errstr";
}
```

and the output I get is like this:

`DBD::Oracle::db do failed: ORA-00917: missing comma (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 36 in 'INSERT INTO MYTEST VALUES (Scotland <*>one inch 1st, Shetland Islands (North) (131), -0.6800, -1.4100, 60.9700, 60.6900)') [for Statement "INSERT INTO MYTEST VALUES (Scotland one inch 1st, Shetland Islands (North) (131), -0.6800, -1.4100, 60.9700, 60.6900)"] at bruce1.pl line 69, <INPUT> line 924.
Content-type:text/html`

meaning it has read the data in successfully but failed. I expect I've made a rookie error, is there anything obvious?

Comment: don't you know interpolating variables into a query is dangerous? Please consider using parameterized statements wherever possible: `my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT ... (?, ?, ...)'); $sth->execute($series, $sheet, ...);`. Also, Perl variables are case sensitive: `$create` and `$Create` are unrelated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL requires alphabetic constants to be quoted:

INSERT INTO MYTEST VALUES ('Scotland one inch 1st', 'Shetland Islands (North) (131)', -0.6800, -1.4100, 60.9700, 60.6900)

If you print the value of $sql, you will see that they aren't.

Comment: Yes, but if you use bindpoints in yor query, then you don't need to worry about quoting strings.